# Reviewing suggested edits: don't rely on the canned comments only!

Tags: discussion

I recently switched sides from *suggesting* edits to *reviewing* suggests. Now I see how when my rejected edits got canned comments (like "too minor...") I didn't really learn how to make better edits.

When on the other hand a reviewer took the time to really explain the reason for the reject I took a step further in understanding what was needed.

The best teachers were those who improved my edit and commented on their edit - for this to generally work we would need the authors of suggested edits to look at their suggests again after reviews happened though.

So for improving quality on AskUbuntu reviewers of suggested edits should take a little more time and tell the editors what in their edit was not appropriate/good enough.

Answer (score 7):

> *The best teachers were those who improved my edit and commented on their edit*

-- it's so very true. And the one prominent user who could be easily associated with this is [@EliahKagan](https://askubuntu.com/users/22949/eliah-kagan). Encounter with him was/is one of the best things on Ask Ubuntu (at least for me). His answers/comments/replies are all well-thought out and he makes every effort to give the other user a fair chance to support his/her argument, help them guide through the site, understand different features, giving his opinion on different policies and all the other stuff which most of the people shy away from. I would take this opportunity to thank him from the bottom of my heart. Also go through [his Activities tab](https://askubuntu.com/users/22949/eliah-kagan?tab=activity&sort=comments) to understand what more I want to say. He still provides detailed description for why he is editing the posts and what not.

In short, the guy is truly amazing and we could learn a lot from him.

<sub>PS: This is not to take any credit away from other truly amazing members and moderators of this community. It's just that someone stood out in my connection with this site. And the whole community has been absolutely wonderful which is the reason why I have visited the site each and every day since my registration (except for one day in the past 3-4 days when I didn't have internet access at all.. Argh..)</sub>

<sub>PPS: And as always on Meta, I started this out as a comment, it got so big that I also incorporated other stuff and posted this in the answers section instead!!</sub>

Comment: My (not so difficult) riddle has been solved - but as you said, he is not the only one.